# Nested stack does not detect changes in the template with RequestMappingTemplateS3Location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a serverless specification with a nested stack, I want to define Type: AWS :: AppSync :: Resolver using RequestMappingTemplateS3Location and ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location, and the templates are in s3. When I update the template the stack does not update the cloudformation.

```
 Resource:
    AppSyncResolverTestStack:
      Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
      DependsOn:
        - GraphQlApi
        - GraphQlSchema
      Properties:
        Parameters:
          MappingTemplatesURL:
            Fn::Join:
              - "/"
              - - "s3:/"
                - ${self:provider.deploymentBucket}
                - 'etc'
                - ${opt:stage}
                - 'mapping_templates_extra'
          GraphQlApiId:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - GraphQlApi
              - ApiId
        TemplateURL:
          Fn::Join:
            - "/"
            - - "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
              - ${self:provider.deploymentBucket}
              - 'etc'
              - ${opt:stage}
              - 'cf-resolvers-2.yml'
```

Nested

```
Parameters:
  MappingTemplatesURL:
    Type: String
  GraphQlApiId:
    Type: String
Resources:
  FCSYSAPIGraphQlResolverFinancialRequest:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Ref: GraphQlApiId
      TypeName: Mutation
      FieldName: FinanceDocumentsApi
      DataSourceName: "FCFinanceApi"
      RequestMappingTemplateS3Location:
        Fn::Join:
          - "/"
          - - Ref: MappingTemplatesURL
            - "fc-finance"
            - "FinanceDocuments.request.vm"
      ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location:
        Fn::Join:
          - "/"
          - - Ref: MappingTemplatesURL
            - "fc-finance"
            - "FinanceDocuments.response.vm"
```

I expect that when I update the template in s3 and deploy my project the cloudformation is updated, but it is maintained with the previous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of CloudFormation. CloudFormation **only updates a resource when its properties change**.

Since the properties `RequestMappingTemplateS3Location` and `ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location` do not change, CloudFormation doesn't update your AppSync Resolver (even though those S3 locations points to "new" content).

One way to solve your problem is to use the [`aws cloudformation package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) command of the AWS CLI. It allows you to define your template with local files:

```yaml
Type: 'AWS::AppSync::Resolver'
Properties:
  ...
  RequestMappingTemplateS3Location: './path/to/local/template/file'
  ...
```

Running

```
aws cloudformation package --template-file mytemplate.yml --s3-bucket mybucket --output-template-file packaged.template
```

returns a copy of your template (`packaged.template`), replacing references to local artifacts with the S3 location where the command uploaded the artifacts. The S3 location name (key) depends on the content (uses MD5). Hence, with this strategy, the property `RequestMappingTemplateS3Location` changes if the content referenced by the S3 location changes.

After that, you can deploy your template with [`aws cloudformation deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html).

Note: this is the same as using [AWS SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-command-reference.html), `sam package` is an alias of `aws cloudformation package`

If working with the serverless framework, another solution is to use the [serverless-appsync-plugin](https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin) which allows to specify mapping templates inline or in a file.

Comment: thanks for your response. This seems to solve my issue but when running the command he tells me that everything was correct but he does not upload the artifacts to s3 and he keeps the same template(I only have one AWS :: AppSync :: Resolver resources)

Comment: Did you specify `--output-template-file`, what do you see in this output file for `RequestMappingTemplateS3Location`?

Comment: I get the same address (RequestMappingTemplateS3Location: /home/oreste/Documents/bacardi/training/mapping-templates/getPost.request.vm) and I got this when I ran the command (``` Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file serverless_result.
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /home/oreste/Documents/bacardi/training/serverless_result --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>```)

Comment: This is strange... it should work. Can you share your input template in a gist? What do you see in the `serverless_result` file?

Comment: I see that you are using the serverless framework together with the `serverless-appsync-plugin`, why don't you use the built-in features of this plugin? You can specify `mappingTemplates` inline or via a file... Updated my answer to mention that solution

Comment: I can not use it because I need to do it in a nested, I updated the repository `https://gitlab.com/oanillar/serverless_template`

Comment: OK, just remove the `resources` key (this is serverless not CF) and move your `Resources` key up and it will work. You should have `Resources` as a top level key. Like this https://pastebin.com/eRyPPVyi

Comment: thank you very much, now it works!!, all because of my novice error, I verify that it solves my issue in my real project and I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Is there any limitation to using the command in the pipeline?, I'm using it in bitbucket but it does not upload the artifacts.

Comment: Not as long as you have the right IAM permissions... Any error message? Are you sure about the template?

Comment: it's as if he did not recognize the path I put (with out errors), I used pwd to see the absolute address and use it in template, then I uploaded the result to s3 with `aws s3 cp` but is the same, (local works well)

Comment: Use *relative* path with something like `../folderup/template` or `./subfolder/template`

Comment: use it too, again local works but without success in the pipeline (I try with --force-upload too)

Comment: Can you share your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/oanillar/serverless_template/blob/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Comment: Can you show `cf-fc-sysapi-resolvers-2.yml` (version in the pipeline) + build logs ?

Comment: I stop the pipeline because for now I'm only interested in updating the template in s3, I check it and it's a copy, (the artifacts are never uploaded to s3)

Comment: If it works locally, there's no reason it fails in the pipeline. Something must be different, hard to help without extra context.

Comment: it's weird, it works for AWS :: Lambda :: Function but not for AWS :: AppSync :: Resolver in the pipeline

Comment: I used an old version of aws in the pipeline, @jogold thank you very much for the help!